# Using json_encode without displaying it on my webpage via echo or print

Tags: javascript, php, json

basically I'm trying to pass an array from PHP to JavaScript, so far it is all working the methods I'm using are:

PHP:

```
echo json_encode($arrayname);
```

JavaScript:

```
$.getJSON( 'myphppage.php', {}, function(data){
     // Do stuff here
});
```

Obviously this echo's the text onto my webpage but I do not want this text to be displayed, I'm just wondering if there is anyway for me to use this without having a chunky array at the top of my webpage. (I tried it without the echo and it doesn't work, I've also gone through countless tutorials on this but no one seems to do it without using echo)

Thanks a lot in advance

---------- Edit -------------

index.js

```
$.getJSON( 'myphppage.php', {}, function(data){
// I loop through the data here
}
}).done(function() {});
```

myphppage.php

```
<?php 
    $servername = "name";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "dbname";

    $connection = mysql_connect($servername,$username); 
    if(!$connection) { 
        die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error()); 
    }else{
        $db_select = mysql_select_db($dbname,$connection); 
        if (!$db_select) { 
            die("Database selection failed:: " . mysql_error()); 
        } 

        $result = mysql_query("select * FROM tablename");
        if (!$result) {
            echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
            exit;
        }

        $array= array();

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            array_push($array, $row);
        }
     echo json_encode($array);
    }
```

Comment: you echo in the file myphppage.php, right? And the file where you have the javascript is another file (or scope) then where you echo the json string?

Comment: yes, I echo in the php file but when i use getJSON in the javascript file it seems to echo it on the webpage as well

Comment: if you use the same file, it's echo'd during the rendering of the page it self and during the getJSON request which results in the problem you see. You should split that.

Comment: I have it in 2 different files, exactly like you stated in the example. Only difference is my getJSON isn't in the index.html its in the index.js file ...

Comment: And the webpage you open is NOT myphpwebpage.php right?

Comment: In summery: I Call $.getJSON( 'myphppage.php', {}, function(data){}); in index.js. I then have a php file (myphppage.php) which creates the array and calls echo json_encode($array);.

Comment: can you share the code of the page where you include the .js file?

Comment: i edited the question accordingly, thanks for your time so far by the way.

Comment: It looks like you are running `mypagephp.php` on page load,as well as returning a response with js.

Comment: Hi Edward, I've not stated the php page to run on page load ... is there something I need to add here? Thanks for your response.

Comment: comment out the javascript call and see if the array is echoed out at the top of the page.

Comment: Yes it is, i haven't asked it to be called anywhere though ... I'll have a look around, cheers so far

Comment: Found it! There was an include somewhere, thank you so much Edward. And thank you Stefan for help also.

Answer (score 0):

Minimal example:

index.html

```
$.getJSON( 'myphppage.php', {}, function(data){
 // Do stuff here
});
```

myphpwebpage.php

```
echo json_encode($arrayname);
```